# PHP Soap Server in JAX-WS Style

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap, websphere

We made a web service for one of our clients with PHP SOAP class. But they said our Soap server is built in RPC style, they need JAX-WS.
When i asked them why, they said, They are using IBM WebSphere 8.5 server. Which has problems with RPC style,  because of RPC is an old technology etc. And They also said that WebSphere doesnt support RPC so well. 
Since Im not expert at SOAP and web services, i did not get it. I did some google but no results for runnnig PHP Soap server in JAX-WS style.
Do you have any idea what should i do ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I think they're mixing the names of the java specifications with the sets of underlying protocols they envelop.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-tip-jaxwsrpc/

> Web services have been around a while now. First there was SOAP. But
>   SOAP only described what the messages looked like. Then there was
>   WSDL. But WSDL didn't tell you how to write web services in Java™.
>   Then along came JAX-RPC 1.0. After a few months of use, the Java
>   Community Process (JCP) folks who wrote that specification realized
>   that it needed a few tweaks, so out came JAX-RPC 1.1. After a year or
>   so of using that specification, the JCP folks wanted to build a better
>   version: JAX-RPC 2.0. A primary goal was to align with industry
>   direction, but the industry was not merely doing RPC web services,
>   they were also doing message-oriented web services. So "RPC" was
>   removed from the name and replaced with "WS" (which stands for web
>   Services, of course). Thus the successor to JAX-RPC 1.1 is JAX-WS 2.0
>   - the Java API for XML-based web services.

For inter-op with non-java, they should avoid JAX-WS or JAX-RPC -- they are meaningless.

Comment: So actually they can handle with my Current RPC service ? Or Have  to write my web service in JAX-WS standart for them ? Still meaningless for me what they want.. Maybe Its because I dont have any idea about Java and its services...